# Exception caught by widgets library. (Assertion failed)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget, flutter-android

While running my Flutter code, I encountered the following error:

```
**-------------------------------Starts Here-----------------------------------**

-------------------Exception caught by widgets library-----------------------

The following assertion was thrown building *CryptoListItem*(dirty)

Assertion failed:

assetName != null

is not true

**--------------------------------Ends Here------------------------------------**
```

Here is the snap of the error:
Error snippet in VS Debug Console:
[image: Error snippet in VS Debug Console]

Please help me resolve this because my project is stuck cause of it.

Answer (score 1):

Set a value to assetName because currently, it is null

Comment: Thankyou!
Error was occurring because it was really null. Actually I was retrieving the image URL from an API and suddenly the API changed the URL in the version update and I was not aware of it.